# How can I install the package in TestComplete?

Tags: testcomplete

1)How can I install the package in Testcomplete tool, Where I have to install. When I Run the application it got failed. The First step itself it got failed.

[image]

Comment: What is the call stack? That will give us a better idea what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

When my team used TestComplete we opened support tickets as needed if we couldn't find the answer through "Help" or the online forum. Their support team was in Russia; sometimes it was 24 hours before we had an answer.

Other options:

A) You can go to the Smart Bear HELP area, search for "Stop on error" and learn how to disable that setting so your apk file can attempt to run the install the  process again; also,

B) Smart Bear has an active online [community](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/TestComplete-Mobile-Application/bd-p/Mobile_Application_Testing) as well where you may find someone else has already asked this question.